# How to copy a very large table into another table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, migration

I have a large table with 110M rows. I would like to copy some of the fields into a new table and here is a rough idea of how I am trying to do:

```
    DECLARE l_seenChangesTo DATETIME DEFAULT '1970-01-01 01:01:01';
    DECLARE l_migrationStartTime DATETIME;

    SELECT NOW() into l_migrationStartTime;

    -- See if we've run this migration before and if so, pick up from where we left off...
    IF EXISTS(SELECT seenChangesTo FROM migration_status WHERE client_user = CONCAT('this-migration-script-', user())) THEN
        SELECT seenChangesTo FROM migration_status WHERE client_user = CONCAT('this-migration-script-', user()) INTO l_seenChangesTo;
        SELECT NOW() as LogTime, CONCAT('Picking up from where we left off: ', l_seenChangesTo) as MigrationStatus;
    END IF;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO newTable
        (field1, field2, lastModified)
        SELECT o.column1 AS field1, 
               o.column2 AS field2,
               o.lastModified 
          FROM oldTable o
          WHERE 
                o.lastModified >= l_seenChangesTo AND
                o.lastModified <= l_migrationStartTime;

    INSERT INTO migration_status (client_user,seenChangesTo) 
        VALUES (CONCAT('this-migration-script-', user()), l_migrationStartTime) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seenChangesTo=l_migrationStartTime;
```

**Context:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newTable` (
    `field1`     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `field2`      tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
    `lastModified`        datetime NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`field1`, `field2`),
    KEY `ix_field1` (`field1`),
    KEY `ix_lastModified` (`lastModified`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oldTable` (
    `column1`     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `column2`      tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
    `lastModified`        datetime NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`column1`, `column2`),
    KEY `ix_column1` (`column1`),
    KEY `ix_lastModified` (`lastModified`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `migration_status` (
        `client_user` char(64) NOT NULL,
        `seenChangesTo` char(128) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (`client_user`)
    );
```

**Note:** I have a few more columns in oldTable. Both oldTable and newTable are in same DB schema using mysql.

What's the general strategy when copying a very table? Should I perform this migration in an iterative manner by copy say 50,000 rows at time.

Comment: is this from mysql to mssql or the other way around?

Comment: after the update so migrating from table to another?

Comment: Both oldTable and newTable are in same DB schema using mysql. I am trying to copy with the same DB into a new table. Updated the question and tags.

Comment: i think your method will just work fine, another way would be to restore the same table and just a matter of removing unnecessary columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert speed doing a migration like this iteratively is going to be dreadfully slow.  Why not `SELECT oldTable INTO OUTFILE`, then `LOAD DATA INFILE` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case, I have some extra columns and also not all the rows need to be copied to the new table. I have some constraints. Would copying from an outfile still be efficient, with column drops and delete?

Comment: @ssk You can choose which fields you export to the outfile just like any other query.  You can select some (or all) columns from a table, join columns from other tables, etc.  The only difference is you direct the result set to a file.  Then you can use that file to do a bulk insert on your new table.  This is standard practice for data warehouse operations, when doing bulk inserts